# In Postman, how to POST binary file use collection runner

Tags: postman, binaryfiles, postman-collection-runner

I am using the Postman Collection Runner to automate a series of API calls.  On one of these API calls I need to submit a binary file as the body of a POST.  When setting up the Collection Runner I see how to select a file, but I can't figure out how to attach that file to the body of the POST request in the "Pre-request Script".

Is it possible in a "Pre-request Script" to load a binary file into the "data" object?

Comment: hi, in your request's body, before using the runner, did you select the "binary" radiobutton ?

Comment: Yes.  I can manually initiate a POST call using Postman, submitting a binary file just fine.  What I am trying to do is execute that same API via the Collection Runner, loading a binary file into the request in a "Pre-request Script".

Comment: well, I'm also a beginner in pre-requests scripting. I'm not sure you can do something like this as postman runner provides the possibility to select the file. Did you have a look to loadash functions ? maybe one of them would allow you to load the binary file in a global variable ? or you may use javascript function to load your file into a global variable ? (sorry I'm also a beginner in javascript ...)

Answer (score 1):

Currently postman collection runner doesn't support file uploads.
You will have to use `newman` to execute your Automation Test Suite(collection).

Have a look at this answer:
[Postman - POST request with file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295434/postman-post-request-with-file-upload)