# Run multiple images/files with iteration data variable using Postman Runner or Newman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

***Scenario***

I have a `POST` request API which accepts **Image or File**. As shown below:

[image]

I can select an image from the Request body as a `form-data` but, here I can select one image at a time.

But I want to upload multiple images or files as a `form-data` variable like `{{image}}` or `{{file}}` while doing Postman-Collection Runner.
As we know, we can only upload **text/JSON/CSV** file as iteration data in **Postman Runner.**

**Questions:**
Is there any way from which we can send **multiple images or files** as Iteration data in Postman Runner or in Newman?

**or**

Can I have a Postman test script that will upload multiple images or files in Postman Runner?

**Or else**

Help me in how to upload multiple images using **Newman**.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: needs detail or clarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Postman, how to POST binary file use collection runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799280/in-postman-how-to-post-binary-file-use-collection-runner)

Comment: @Babak It's pretty, clear, but not possible: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799280/in-postman-how-to-post-binary-file-use-collection-runner or https://blog.postman.com/run-collections-with-file-uploads-using-newman/

Comment: @ChristianBaumann
Thanks for this reference: https://blog.postman.com/run-collections-with-file-uploads-using-newman/

I got pretty good clarification on this.

But Can you please tell me,

Is there any way to send multiple files in the `POST` request asynchronously? but not at the same time as it's mentioned in the above link.

Comment: [Moorthi Rajendiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12267300) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67090829) saying "I referred the below link and updated the setting. Now it is working for me. [https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023574653-Storage-of-file-Working-Directory-in-reference-for-collections](https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023574653-Storage-of-file-Working-Directory-in-reference-for-collections)"

Comment: Thanks, @MoorthiRajendiran. It really helped me a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you can possibly do is , create those many test cases in your iteration data file. for example if you want to upload 10 images so you can create 10 testcases in your test data file and run it as a part of collection runner

Comment: Well, Thanks for this. But, I know this, and I did like this only. AND, it's time-consuming and it won't look good in `collection` if you have too many files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solve it without newman.

I exported my collection in json and set "src": "{{value}}" in the body of exported .json file:

```
"body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": [
                        {
                            "key": "file",
                            "type": "file",
                            "src": "{{value}}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

After that I added new json file with different files for value:

```
[{
  "path": "post",
  "value": "1.png"
}, {
  "path": "post",
  "value": "2.png"
}, {
  "path": "post",
  "value": "3.png"
}, {
  "path": "post",
  "value": "4.png"
}]
```

Be sure that these files exists in working directory of postman (it can be set in settings)

After that I imported these collection back into postman.
The form-data of the request is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN6zP.png)

When we run the collection we choose in data the json file with values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EPQj.png)

The result was that my request executes 4 times and every time it uploads different file.